# Rounding a floating number

Tags: java, double, floating-point-precision

I am trying to create a class dedicated to the floating point precision management.

Actually, it takes your double and the number of decimal it has to be rounded, then everytime you will modify it with `set(double)`, the number will be automatically rounded.

```
public class Precision {

    public Precision(int rounding, double n)    {
        setRounding(rounding);
        set(n);
    }

    public double get() {
        return this.n;
    }

    public void set(double n)   {
        this.n = Math.round(n * Math.pow(10, rounding)) / rounding;
    }

    public void inc(double n)   {
        set(get() + n);
    }

    public int getRounding()    {
        return this.rounding;
    }

    public void setRounding(int rounding)   {
        if (rounding > 324)
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Can't round numbers after 324 decimals");
        else
            this.rounding = rounding;
    }

    public void copy(Precision p)   {
        this.rounding = p.getRounding();
        this.n = p.n;
    }

    private int rounding;
    private double n;
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected, when I do operations on the number it simply doesn't set the expected number. For instance:

```
Precision p = new Precision(2, 0);
// Here p.n is worth 0.00
p.set(8.6596)
// Here p.n is worth 432.5
p.inc(3.2);
// Here p.n is worth 21785
```

Comment: What is an example of it "not working as expected"?

Comment: [Math.round()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) returns a `long`

Comment: I added an example to my message

Comment: Ok, so at this point you should do some debugging to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the formula you are using is not working properly. You can try this instead:

```
this.n = (int) (n * Math.pow(10, rounding)) / Math.pow(10, rounding);
```

Comment: Oh thank I got it now, I wanted to do `Math.round(n * Math.pow(10, rounding)) / Math.pow(10, rounding)` instead.

Comment: @LoveMetal There was a mistake, see edit. Changed 100.0 to `Math.pow(10, rounding)`.